# Move /migrate django data into new table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an Event table. I have 2 different types of attendees, staff and student. What I'd like to do is have the attendees in a sperate table.

The **Event** table holds:

```
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
     about = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

     student_attendees = models.ManyToManyField(StudentProfile, null=True, blank=True)
     staff_attendees = models.ManyToManyField(StaffProfile, null=True, blank=True)
```

The **Attendee** table would have:

```
     event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
     content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
     object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     profile = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How would I go about transferring or migrating the event student & staff attendee data into it's own Attendee table. (I'm not using South, and at this point would like to avoid using it.). Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: South is made to do exactly this. Why are you want to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just dump the data in json and manually separate them into different fixtures, then alter the tables (or re-create the db) and load the data.

Or just write a script to manually select some fields and pickle them or dump as json manually, or even as CSV:

```
with open('students.csv', 'w') as st_file:
    writer = csv.writer(st_file)
    for a in Attendee.objects.filter(profile__status='student'):
        st_file.writerow(a.event_id, a.content_type, a.object_id, a.profile, ...)
```

Then make a simple script to load the data.

```
with open('students.csv', 'w') as st_file:
    reader = csv.reader(st_file)
    for row in reader:
        event = Event.objects.get(id=row[0])
        event.student_attendees.add(Student.objects.get(row[2]))
```

(this implies object_id is identical to the new id in StudentProfile table)

Of course, back the database up before doing this.

Actually, there's a better way:

```
 python manage.py dumpdata app.event app.attendee --indent=4 > events.json
```

Then edit to fit the new tables, then

```
 python manage.py loaddata events.json
```

Comment: Sounds painful enough to start thinking about south or evolution.

Comment: You also can use dumpdata & loaddata.

Comment: You need to read the whole question again. He is basically asking how to separate a single model into two models after the fact which won't work by simply performing a dumpdata & loaddata.

Comment: @culebrón Thanks for the suggestions! I'll be sure to try it out. I'm a Django n00b still, so you when you say 'backup the database', how would I go about doing that?

Comment: python manage.py dumpdata -e contenttypes > fixtures/initial_data.json

Comment: That will dump the current data base (except the contenttypes) into a json file which can be loaded again at a later point with python manage.py loaddata fixtures/initial_data.json. The file will also automatically be imported when using syncdb.

Comment: Would the dumpdata/loaddata method correctly handle relationships?